# Month not increasing after Increment of a Year in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I am saving due date of every transaction with next number of month. It is working perfect for 2019, but doesn't work for 2020 and so on.

```
string Due_Date_Sample;
DateTime Due_Date_var;
public static string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Main.connectionString))
{
    string commandString = "SELECT TOP 1 FORMAT(Due_Date,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS Due_Date FROM Transactions where Plot_Code='" + Plot_Code_var + "' ORDER BY Due_Date DESC;";

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);

    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        date_control_var = 2;
        Due_Date_Sample = (dr["Due_Date"].ToString());
        Due_Date_var = DateTime.Parse(Due_Date_Sample.ToString());
    }

    dr.Close();
}

Due_Date_var = Convert.ToDateTime(Due_Date_var.ToString(format)).AddMonths(1);
commandstring1 = "INSERT INTO Transactions (Trans_Code,Plot_Code,Plot_No,Inst_No,Inst_Amt,Status,Due_Date,Balance) values ('"
               + Transaction_Code_var + "','" + Plot_Code_var + "','" + Plot_No_var + "','"
               + Inst_No_var + "','" + Inst_Amt_var + "','Due','" + Due_Date_var.ToString(format) + "','" + (Bal_var - int.Parse(Inst_Amt_var)) + "');";//Saving Transactions

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandstring1, sqlCon);

sqlCon.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

[image]

Comment: How is `Due_Date_var` initially being set? And what is the value of `format`?

Comment: 1. Show the content of `Due_Date_var` and `format`. 2. Always use [parameterised queries](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx).

Comment: I added them too

Comment: **FIRST and foremost**: ***NEVER EVER*** build your SQL statements by concatenating together the SQL string like you're doing it here - you're opening up your system to **SQL injection attacks** - the #1 vulnerability out there on the internet. Learn to use **parametrized queries** instead! And secondly: if you want to execute an `INSERT` command - do *not* use `.ExecuteReader` (since you're not really reading a result set) - but use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead

Comment: It seems that dr["Due_Date"] returns a DateTime value, so please remove all those .ToString()s and just cast to DateTime directly

Comment: @marc_s ! I used .ExecuteNonQuery but it is working same as before.

Comment: By the way, I was expecting a proper Answer which could clearly mention my mistake and guide me to right way.

Comment: I even tried Dateadd function in query but the working is same as before

Comment: If you are working with dates, leave them as dates. You are string formatting them so many times it's no suprise that it does not function as expected. It's entirely likely you can do this with just one simple SQL statement. If you want this to work properly, remove all of the date formatting (including that in the SQL) and try again. Also learn to debug so that you can inspect variable values at run time

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your problem using Entity framework it is working correct no need such long code as you written and EF is recommended by Microsoft for new Desktop and web apps check simple code in using EF

```
using (var context = new ProductionContext())
{

    DateTime PayDate = PaymentDatePicker.Value;  //Payment or Transaction Date 
    DateTime DueDate = PayDate.AddMonths(1);  // due date = Payment date + one month 
    var install = new Instalment();  // object of instalment class/table

   install.PaymentDate = PayDate;
   install.NextDueDate = DueDate;
   context.Instalments.Add(install);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image: database Result check image]